# How to configure Apache Ignite in Redash

Tags: database, dashboard, ignite, redash

I need to configure Apache ignite in Redash for BI dashboard but couldn't figure out how to do the same since there is no direct support for ignite in Redash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using Python query runner, which is available **for [stand-alone installs](https://redash.io/help/open-source/setup) only**. It allows you to run arbitrary Python code, in which you can query Apache Ignite via JDBC.

First, add `redash.query_runner.python` query runner to `settings.py`:
[image: add query runner]

and install Python JDBC bridge module together with dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-jpype
sudo easy_install JayDeBeApi
```

Then after VM restart you should add Python data source (you might need to tweak module path):
[image: add data source]

And then you can actually run the query (you will need to provide Apache Ignite core JAR and JDBC connection string as well):
[image: edit query]

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver', 'jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost', {}, '/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/ignite/ignite-core/2.3.2/ignite-core-2.3.2.jar')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select c.Id, c.CreDtTm from TABLE.Table c")
data = curs.fetchall()

result = {"columns": [], "rows": []}
add_result_column(result, "Id", "Identifier", "string")
add_result_column(result, "CreDtTm", "Create Date-Time", "integer")

for d in data:
        add_result_row(result, {"Id": d[0], "CreDtTm": d[1]})
```

Unfortunately there's no direct support for JDBC in Redash (that I'm aware of) so all that boilerplate is needed.

Comment: Thank you @Alamar for the quick response.

Comment: I am having difficulty in installing Redhat similar below packages.     sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-jpype
sudo easy_install JayDeBeApi,   I am able to see python in datasources but its giving jaydebeapi module issues, and also i cannot see .egg jaydebeapi file in python location, i can only see egg.info files

Comment: @Sandy you will have to figure out how to install those modules. `yum` perhaps instead of `apt-get`?